# How to add a house icon to the menu?

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to modify my menu so that it there will be a little house icon at the beginning and when the user clicks that house icon he will be redirected to the homepage. The problem is I don't know what to change or where... 
I have the code in html+css

```
<li class="home"><a href="#"><div class="home-image"></div></a></li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, but where should I insert this code? I think I left out a basic detail: I want to make the changes in the "top menu" module of prestashop.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<li class="home"><a href="#"><div class="home-image"><span class="icon-home"></span></div></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Font Awesome/Bootstrap/Google.

**Font Awesome:**

Paste the below code in Head section [ `<head>paste it here</head>` ]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and add this

```
<li class="home"><a href="#"><div class="home-image"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></div></a></li>
```

**Bootstrap Icons:**

Paste the below code in Head section [ `<head>paste it here</head>` ]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and add this

```
<li class="home"><a href="#"><div class="home-image"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></div></a></li>
```

**Google Icons:**

Paste the below code in Head section [ `<head>paste it here</head>` ]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

and add this

```
<li class="home"><a href="#"><div class="home-image"><i class="material-icons">home</i></div></a></li>
```

You need to add style to change the size of the icon.

Examples:

```
<i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px;">home</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know anything about css then  just paste this code

```
<li class="home"><a href="http://google.com/"><div class="home-image">
    <img width="50" height="50"  style="margin-top:3px" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/origami-colored-pencil/256/blue-home-icon.png">
</div></a></li>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/waseemmachloy/ncsFY/)